# social media icons dont show on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

im making social media icons on footer, it shows fine when im on PC, but it disapear when im on mobile. Here is my code

```
<footer class="container-fluid">
<p>Copyright 2016</p>
<ul id="socialmedia">
    <li><a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-fw"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-fw"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is the CSS

```
#socialmedia {
margin:0 auto;
display:block;
width:22%;
height:50px;
padding:0;
position:relative;
top:-45px;
left:-540px;
background:#0C5060;
}
#socialmedia li {
display:block;
float:left;
width:calc(25% - 1px);
text-align:center;
}
#socialmedia a {
display:block;
padding:5px 0;
font-size:24px;
color:#F8F8F8;
}
#socialmedia a:hover {
background-color:#fff;
color:#166D81;
}
.socialmedia-mobile a {
display:block;
width:25%;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}
```

And here is below the screenshot on how footer looks on PC
and how it looks on phone

[image: footer on PC]

[image: footer on Phone]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `position: relative;` with `top` and `left` set to negative values on `#socialmedia` selector which is causing the problem.

Try to use @media queries to style elements differently on different screen sizes, for example:

```
#socialmedia {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:22%;
    height:50px;
    padding:0;
    background:#0C5060;
}

#socialmedia > li {
    display:block;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #socialmedia {
        position:relative;
        top:-45px;
        left:-540px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #socialmedia > li {
        display:block;
        width:25%;
        float:left;
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

**Also please, format you code!**

Good luck! :)